# How to call AS3 Switch

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

I am struggling a bit with my switch statement (I've never used switch before). I have a hit test for when my object reaches the top or bottom of the stage. When this happens, I want to switch states (the game in question is a simple platformer that allows the player to switch the gravity when they hit a new surface. Below is my current code:

```
{
    ...

    if(player.hitTestObject(bottom)) {
        //Switch state to normal
    }
    if(player.hitTestObject(top)) {
        //Switch state to inverted
    }
}

switch (myGrav){
    case "NORMAL":
        trace("Normal")
        player.gotoAndPlay(1);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 376.5;

    case "INVERTED":
        trace("Inverted")
        player.gotoAndPlay(8);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 12;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's what I want, right? So if 'player' hits 'bottom', the state will be switched to NORMAL. Then the changes in the NORMAL case are applied.

Answer (score 2):

Cases within your switch statement are missing a `break`; therefore, code will continue to execute through the switch statement.

This should be:

```
var myGrav:String = "NORMAL";

if (player.hitTestObject(bottom))
    myGrav = "NORMAL";

if (player.hitTestObject(top))
    myGrav = "INVERTED";

switch (myGrav)
{
    case "NORMAL":
        trace("Normal")
        player.gotoAndPlay(1);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 376.5;
        break;

    case "INVERTED":
        trace("Inverted")
        player.gotoAndPlay(8);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 12;
        break;
}
```

Comment: When I run this, I get "Normal" in my output. But if I pass either top or bottom, nothing changes.Could this be a problem with my hitTest object now?

Comment: This tests for cases `NORMAL` and `INVERTED`.  If you want to pass `TOP` and `BOTTOM`, add additional `case` statements.

Comment: The case constant matching the switch expression (`myGrav`) is what executes.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. When I said pass top or bottom, I meant when my player actually passes the point (satisfying the hitTest), not passing 'top' and 'bottom' to my switch statement.

Comment: Inside or after the switch code executes, set `myGrav` to null or a default value to prevent cases from executing again.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer less variables when I can get away with it.

```
switch (true){
    case (player.hitTestObject(bottom)):
        trace("Normal")
        player.gotoAndPlay(1);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 376.5;
        break;

    case (player.hitTestObject(top)):
        trace("Inverted")
        player.gotoAndPlay(8);
        oktoJump = false;
        player.y = 12;
        break;
}
```

Comment: I thought cases were always constant.  That's pretty cool - nice answer.

Comment: @JasonSturges Nope the case part of a switch is an evaluation to whats defined in the switch section. In this case the first one from top down to eval to true wins.